# Cordova Android run failed

Tags: node.js, cordova, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

I'm trying to create a cordova project on my machine, but I can't launch the android emulator to check that the project is working properly. Here's the error I get:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKJY0.png)

However, when I run the avdmanger list avd command myself, I don't get any error (although I can't see the devices I've added under android studio):
[avdmanager result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNgbc.png)

Here are the variables in my .bashrc file. It's written in the Cordovia documentation that the required version of java is 11, so I'm normally good at this...

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/loris/Android/Sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$ANDROID_HOME

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/latest/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/build-tools/33.0.2
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator


export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.19.0-openjdk-amd64
export CORDOVA_JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.22+7

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/gradle/gradle-7.6.4/bin
```

Here is also the list of my android studio installations:
[params1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQtFr.png)

[params2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLwzM.png)

[params3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCZsz.png)

I really hope someone can help me with this problem